# MongoDB stop automatic deletion of records

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB has a TTL (time to live) feature described [in the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/), which allows documents to expire after a certain amount of time, and be automatically deleted from a collection.

The documentation gives the following example, which creates a TTL index on a field containing a BSON date object, and sets an expiration time to happen 3600 seconds (1 hour) after the `createdAt` date:

```
db.log_events.ensureIndex({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

---

What I have not been able to find is how to reverse this process, that is how to stop the automatic expiration of documents after having set an expiration.

How do I disable the TTL (time to live) within a given collection in MongoDB?

Comment: dropIndex() http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/remove-indexes/

Comment: Just remove the index or drop that attribute. :)

Comment: Oh, of course, that would do it.  If someone posts it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the index from your collection

```
db.log_events.dropIndex("expireAt");
```

or `expireAt_1` (the system generated name), depending on whether a name was specified when creating the index.

Refer to [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/) for further details.